# Make all filter options 'active' on initialisation - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-wbff3f

The above stackblitz will demo a few pipe filters. If you click on locations of "North, South or East", it will populate the *ngFor loop - these filters can be selected on/off and use a "multifilter pipe". By default I want all these filter buttons "active" or "on" to show the complete populated list to begin with, allowing you to then click the filters off. Otherwise, the list if blank on first load!

**.html file**

```
<button [class.active]="entry.isLocationActive" (click)="toggle(entry.location); entry.isLocationActive = !entry.isLocationActive" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique">{{entry.location}}</button>


<my-timeline-entry *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filter:filteredYear:'year'| multifilter:filteredLocations:'location' " timeEntryHeader={{entry.year}} timeEntryContent={{entry.detail}} timeEntryPlace={{entry.place}} timeEntryLocation={{entry.location}}></my-timeline-entry>
```

**.ts file**

```
filteredLocations: string[] = [];

toggle(location) {
    let indexLocation = this.filteredLocations.indexOf(location);
    if (indexLocation >= 0) {
      this.filteredLocations = this.filteredLocations.filter((i) => i !== location);
    } else {
      this.filteredLocations.push(location);
    }
}
```

I've played around with pre-populating the `filteredLocations` object with all the values, so it starts off with them all therefore active.

I managed to get the 'active' class to be active on first load but that did not carry through to the pipe filter. I'm sure its not a big change just can't see it, any help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filteredLocations = this.timeLine.map(a => a.location);
```

Adding this to the .ts file and replacing the empty `filteredLocations: string[] = [];`

I wasn't far off initially in the end. Hope it helps others.